# What does "texting reporters possible guesses" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Trump slams damning New York Times op-ed as 'gutless'](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/09/05/politics/nyt-trump-resistance-op-ed/index.html)

> Trump administration officials, struggling to mount a defense to Bob
>   Woodward’s tell-all book, were stunned when the editorial was
>   published Wednesday afternoon, left guessing and quietly pointing
>   fingers at other officials as they tried to figure out who wrote the
>   op-ed, even **texting reporters possible guesses**.

I don't understand "texting reporters possible guesses".
It maybe means

> ... officials sending text message to reporters ask them about who is the
>   possible suspects

or

> ... officials sending text message to reporters give them the possbile
>   suspects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the second one. The officials are sending guesses (possible suspects) to reporters. We can understand this from the context, since the officials were the ones trying to figure it out. Also, if we wanted to say that the officials were *requesting* guesses from the reports, we would use ***for***:

> Officials were texting reporters ***for*** possible guesses.